# Android Studio, Java: Open new Activity after logging in a User

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I have a login screen and after I put in my credentials and tapped on Sign In, if user and password are correct, I want the next Activity to open up. (PadsActivity in this case). Code is as follows:

```
package com.example.beatpad.data;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.example.beatpad.data.model.LoggedInUser;
import com.example.beatpad.ui.login.DatabaseService;
import com.example.beatpad.ui.login.LoginActivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Class that handles authentication with login credentials and retrieves user information.
 */
public class LoginDataSource {

    public DatabaseService dbs = new DatabaseService(null);

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        try {
            if (dbs.checkUser(username, password)) {
                return new Result.Success<>(username);
            } else {
                dbs.createUser(username, password);
                if  (dbs.checkUser(username, password)) {
                    return new Result.Success<>(username);
                } else {
                    return new Result.Error(new IOException("Dataset invalid"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I did the following:

```
package com.example.beatpad.data;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.example.beatpad.data.model.LoggedInUser;
import com.example.beatpad.ui.login.DatabaseService;
import com.example.beatpad.ui.login.LoginActivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Class that handles authentication with login credentials and retrieves user information.
 */
public class LoginDataSource {

    public DatabaseService dbs = new DatabaseService(null);

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PadsActivity.class);
        try {
            if (dbs.checkUser(username, password)) {
                startActivity(i);
                return new Result.Success<>(username);
            } else {
                dbs.createUser(username, password);
                if  (dbs.checkUser(username, password)) {
                    startActivity(i);
                    return new Result.Success<>(username);
                } else {
                    return new Result.Error(new IOException("Dataset invalid"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }
}
```

It marks PadsActivity and both startActivity's in red. Cannot resolve symbol / method.

Comment: Tried `Clean Project` and `Rebuild` ?

Answer (score 1):

The method startActivity() is available from the Context class and you are not extending it here, you should return the result to an Activity and then perform the navigation from there.
Of course, to be of use with Context.startActivity(), all activity classes must have a corresponding  declaration in their package's AndroidManifest.xml.